# Access VBA run query with values passed from a list box

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have made this form in Access and I am hoping to do the following task.

The list box here contains two columns, and can be multi-selected. I want to use the values second column (the right column) and pass them into a query that I set up for the "test2" button below.

[image]

And here is my VBA code for the on-click event for the button.

```
Private Sub test2_Click()
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim qdef As dao.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb


'Build the IN string by looping through the listbox
For i = 0 To Select_Counties2.ListCount - 1
    If Select_Counties2.Selected(i) Then
        strIN = strIN & "'" & Select_Counties2.Column(1, i) & "',"
    End If
Next i

'Create the WHERE string, and strip off the last comma of the IN string
strWhere = " WHERE County_GEOID in " & "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & ")"

strSQL = strSQL & strWhere

    
Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("User query results", strSQL)
qdef.Close
Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "User query results", acViewNormal
End Sub
```

I was getting this error:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I did wrong in the code? Thank you!

Comment: You only have WHERE without having a query type or data source

Comment: What is the value of `strSQL`? I don't see where you set this. I just see the `Where` clause.

Comment: A little debugging effort should reveal logic flaws. Step debug your code. Use Debug.Print statements to see values of variables, especially long SQL statements built with code. Use the Watches window.

Comment: yes indeed, you can add `Debug.print ("my SQL request : " & strSQL)`

Comment: My bad. I missed the select statement. I just added it in. `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM age` but the query returned nothing

Comment: You should now have a query named "User query results" in your main database window, created from running your VBA. You should be able to test and adjust the query from there to see why it is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In this example from microsoft they call application.refreshwindow without explanation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-createquerydef-method-dao

What I think is going on is that your code fails because access cannot find the query that was just added to it's collection of queries.  Also your generated sql is no longer valid.
So: replace my sql with your own valid sql

```
Private Sub test2_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "PARAMETERS GEOID Number; " 'without valid sql this code doesn't run so 
                                    'replace my sql with your own.
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT GEOID FROM Counties"
Set db = CurrentDb

For i = 0 To Select_Counties2.ListCount - 1
    If Select_Counties2.Selected(i) Then
        strIN = strIN & Select_Counties2.Column(1, i) & ","
    End If
Next i

strWhere = " WHERE County_GEOID in " & "(" & Left(strIN, Len(strIN) - 1) & ")"
strSQL = strSQL & strWhere
Debug.Print strSQL
'now the important bit:
db.CreateQueryDef ("User query results") 'create the query
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow 'refresh database window so access knows it has a new query.
'query will now be visible in database window.  make sure to delete the query between runs
 'Access will throw an error otherwise
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("User query results")
qdef.SQL = strSQL
qdef.Close
Set qdef = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "User query results", acViewNormal
End Sub
```